# Why when loading a scene it's taking too much time?

Tags: unity, c#

I have two scenes in the Hierarchy when running the game.
And this script attached to empty GameObject:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LoadScenes : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        if (!SceneManager.GetSceneByName("The Space Station").IsValid())
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(1, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
            StartCoroutine(WaitForSceneLoad(SceneManager.GetSceneByName("The Space Station")));
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator WaitForSceneLoad(Scene scene)
    {
        while (!scene.isLoaded)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
        SceneManager.SetActiveScene(SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex(1));
    }
}
```

But it's taking like 3-4 seconds until it's getting to the line:

```
SceneManager.SetActiveScene(SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex(1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scene loading always depends on resource (prefabs, game objects, audios, textures, etc.) usage. If scene has a lot of objects in it, or scripts instantiate objects in awake or start methods, scene loading will take much more time.

[Async Object Management in Unity3D Forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-can-i-instantiate-a-gameobject-async.160737/).

[LoadSceneAsync Unity3D Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html).